# Clone Windows 10 to new disk

Tags: windows, qemu, clone

I have problem with Windows 10. I've installed Windows 10 on Qemu virtual machine and I need to clone this image to physical disk. I use ntfstool for do that.

Unfortunatelly my Windows doesn't boot because UNIQUEID for disk is different. I can change disk uniqueid to correct and boot windows but I must change uniqueid in Windows VM to 0x00000000. I have a system which automatically save windows images to correct disk but all disks have uniqueid as 0x00000000. I need to have image with the same id.

My questions are:
1. Can I change unique id for Windows disks without loosing boot ability?
2. Can I tell Qemu which id should new disk have?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

+1 Run [sysprep](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721940(v=ws.10).aspx) to prepare system for cloning then go with [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) to prepare image of your VM and to write it on physical host.

Comment: I don't use clonezilla, I use ntfsclone because I want to automat that process. Unfortunatelly after sysprep my system goes to reboot loop. :(

Answer (score 2):

There is guide [how to prepare windows system before cloning](https://www.petri.com/using-syspre-windows-10).

In two words, you need to use [sysprep](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721940(v=ws.10).aspx) before cloning to remove system-specific data from Windows.

Comment: Thank you for a suggestion but It doesn't work. After sysprep I got some questions during boot and everything takes too much time. Anyway I didn't run cloned system because it went to reboot loop. :(

Previously I manually installed system on disk with id 0x00000000 and clone with ntfsclone. All my machines has partition with that ID. Now I wan't to automate that process and use qemu to create system but I have problem because I can't tell qemu to create disk with specific disk id.